# Best practice for send message to many applications in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, messaging, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic with many partitions. I want many applications read all messages from this topic. Some applications read frequently and other at midnight.

I don't find any help, for this problem in stackoverflow or in book.

How i can implement that in kafka ?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions on this site are supposed to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need Kafka Consumers in order to let your applications consume messages from Kafka topics. In case each of your application needs to consume all messages, then you'd have to assign a distinct group-id to every application.

Kafka assigns the partitions of a topic to the consumer in a group. It also guarantees that a message is only ever read by a single consumer in the group. Partitions is the level of parallelism in Kafka (if you have 2 partitions then you can have up to 2 consumers in the same consumer group).

**Example:**
Say you have topic `example-topic` with 5 partitions and 2 applications each of which must consume all the messages from `example-topic`. You will need two distinct consumer groups (1 per application), say `group.id=app-group-1` for the first app and `group.id=app-group-2` for your second app. Within each consumer group, you can start at most 5 consumers consuming messages from your topic. Therefore, up to 5 consumers will subscribe to topic `example-topic` and belong to `group.id=app-group-1` and another 5 consumers that will subscribe to topic `example-topic` and belong to `group.id=app-group-2`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That's what I was looking for. Sorry for my bad english